# Shell script find cmin evaluates on directory, not on files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find, aix

I have a directory with files in them, when the files in this directory are older than 10 minutes, I would like to receive a notification from our monitoring.
With our monitoring I'm creating a SSH session which executes a shell script to check the age of the files in the directory.

The shell script only shows the files in the checked directory when the directory is older than 10 minutes, and not the individual files.

See below example (I've tested this example at Nov 27th, 09:22)

There are files older than 10 minutes (since Nov 27th, 09:22):

```
system:/mls_bmp/indir/BT> ll
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonic sonic 845 Nov 24 08:04 BRMLREL20171124080420572
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonic sonic 845 Nov 24 08:17 BRMLREL20171124081723685
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonic sonic 845 Nov 24 08:17 BRMLREL20171124081729805
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonic sonic 845 Nov 27 08:49 BRMLREL20171127084911037
-rw-r--r-- 1 sonic sonic 845 Nov 27 08:49 BRMLREL20171127084920817
```

However, this find command shows amount 0:

```
system:/mls_bmp/indir> find /mls_bmp/indir/BT -prune -cmin +10 -exec ls {} \; | wc -l | xargs
0
```

And this is because the directory in which I check is younger than 10 minutes (since Nov 27th, 09:22):

```
system:/mls_bmp/indir> ll
drwxrwxrwx 4 oracle dba 20480 Nov 27 09:15 BT
```

I don't want to check subdirs, so using the statement: `find /mls_bmp/indir/BT/* -prune -cmin +10 -exec ls {} \; | wc -l | xargs` is not an option.

Comment: Instead of `-prune`, how about `-type f -maxdepth 1`?

Answer (score 0):

`find` starts on the specified directory, then looks at its contents (then their contents, etc). This means that that `-prune` applies to the directory (/mls_bmp/indir/BT), and prevents `find` from looking at the files inside it. As @BenjaminW said in a comment, use `-type f -maxdepth 1` instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. Currently I'm working on a AIX system, where the maxdepth function is not available so therefor I had to use the -prune parameter. I'll check if i can update the find command to get the latest version so I can use the maxdepth parameter.

Comment: @PeterSondag According to the [man page at ibm.com](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm), AIX's `find` command has a really minimal set of expression terms. You *might* be able to do it with `find /mls_bmp/indir/BT -type f -cmin +10 -exec ls {} \; -o '!' -name BT -prune`